# Leer archivos en una lista de diccionarios recibidos desde React

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, reactjs, flask

A traves de JS y con ayuda de axios, estoy generando un `FormData()` a partir de un formulario de la siguientes manera:

```
const params = {
 'product_id': 3,
 'quantity': 10,
 'products: [{
    'name': 'X',
    'file_product': 'x.png'
  },{
    'name': 'Y',
    'file_product': 'Y.png'
  }]
  ...moreparams
}
const formData = new FormData();

Object.keys(params).forEach((key) => {
  if (typeof params[key] !== 'object') formData.append(key, params[key]);
  else formData.append(key, JSON.stringify(params[key]));
});
```

Esa informacion la recibo en Python con Flask, donde puedo hacer un print de `product_id`, `quantity` u algun otro parametro recibido. Incluso puedo leer el `name` de `products` pero no puedo leer el archivo como tal.

```
data = request.form.to_dict(flat=False)
print(data)
product_id = data.get('product_id')
quantity = data.get('quantity')
products = data.get('products')
        
for product in products:
  print('hi')
  print(product.files['file_product']) # Aqui truena
```

Si hago una prueba de la siguiente manera, sin meter los archivos dentro de un listado de diccionarios, si puedo hacerlo sin problemas y obtener el archivo y manipularlo.

```
if "user_file" not in request.files:
    return {'message': 'No has subido el archivo.'}, 400

file    = request.files["user_file"]
```

Como hago para leer los archivos en una lista de diccionarios en Python cuando se envían a través de JS?

Comment: ábrelo y léelo `with open("archivo,txt") as f: f.readlines()`

Comment: @Christian Normalmente son imagenes o PDFs. Necesito la informacion del archivo para que una vez recibido, poderlo subir a S3. Esto que propones me ayuda?

Comment: no he trabajado con s3. Si abres un archivo en modo de escritura se creará dicho archivo y luego puedes seleccionarlo para hacer la subida